# \fancyhf line break issue - align to top?

Tags: vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

In my header whenever I have a linebreak the whole header changes its alignment.
But I just want the new line to come in below, not the whole header ajusting to what seems to be `vertical-align = middle`, I rather need something like `vertical-align = top`.

[image]
Here is my problem, as you can see the top line isn't aligned with the left and right part anymore, but it should always be starting at the same height from the top:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, notitlepage, twoside, twocolumn, openany]{book}

\newcommand{\StartPageNumber}{7}
\newcommand{\Issue}{First Issue}
\newcommand{\AuthorLastName}{Author}
\newcommand{\TitleHd}{Title, very long sometimes too long\\- multiple lines
}

% Kopfzeile
\usepackage[fit]{truncate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[HRO]{\fontsize{8}{8} \thepage}
\fancyhf[HLE]{\fontsize{8}{8} \thepage}
\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\fontsize{8}{8} \Issue}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf[HCE,HCO]{
    \centering\fontsize{8}{8}
    \emph{\AuthorLastName}, \TitleHd
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}
    \setcounter{page}{\StartPageNumber}
    TEST
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tabular:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, notitlepage, twoside, twocolumn, openany]{book}

\newcommand{\StartPageNumber}{7}
\newcommand{\Issue}{First Issue}
\newcommand{\AuthorLastName}{Author}
\newcommand{\TitleHd}{Title, very long sometimes too long\\- multiple lines
}

% Kopfzeile
\usepackage[fit]{truncate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[HRO]{\fontsize{8}{8} \thepage}
\fancyhf[HLE]{\fontsize{8}{8} \thepage}
\fancyhf[HRE,HLO]{\fontsize{8}{8} \Issue}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf[HCE,HCO]{
    \centering\fontsize{8}{8}
    \emph{\AuthorLastName}, \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}\TitleHd\end{tabular}}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}
    \setcounter{page}{\StartPageNumber}
    TEST
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks :) Could you explain what `\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]` does? And what do the tabular params`[t]{@{}l}` do?